# No property timestamp found for type int! Traversed path: ScoreCard.score

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest, spring-boot

While trying to run the spring boot application, I am getting the below errors.

1:

> **org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userStatsController'**

2:

> **Error creating bean with name 'scoreCardRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method
>   public abstract java.util.List.microservices.book.gamification.repository.ScoreCardRepository.findByUserIdOrderByScoreTimestampDesc(java.lang.Long)!
>   No property timestamp found for type int! Traversed path:
>   ScoreCard.score.**

I am using the H2 database.

**ScoreCardRepository.java**

```java
public interface ScoreCardRepository extends CrudRepository<ScoreCard, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT SUM(s.score) FROM microservices.book.gamification.domain.ScoreCard s WHERE s.userId = :userId GROUP BY s.userId")
    int getTotalScoreForUser(@Param("userId") final Long userId);

    @Query("SELECT NEW microservices.book.gamification.domain.LeaderBoard(s.userId, SUM(s.score))"
            + "FROM microservices.book.gamification.domain.ScoreCard s "
            + "GROUP BY s.userId ORDER BY SUM(s.score) DESC")
    List<LeaderBoardRow> findFirst10();

    List<ScoreCard> findByUserIdOrderByScoreTimestampDesc(Long userId);
}
```

**ScoreCard.java**

```java
@Entity
public class ScoreCard {

    public static final int DEFAULT_SCORE = 20;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "CARD_ID")
    private Long cardId;

    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    private Long userId;

    @Column(name = "ATTEMPT_ID")
    private Long attemptId;

    @Column(name = "SCORE_TS")
    private long scoreTimeStamp;

    @Column(name = "SCORE")
    private int score;

    public ScoreCard() {
    }

    public ScoreCard(Long userId, Long attemptId) {
        this.cardId = null;
        this.userId = userId;
        this.attemptId = attemptId;
        this.scoreTimeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        this.score = DEFAULT_SCORE;
    }

    public Long getCardId() {
        return cardId;
    }

    public Long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public Long getAttemptId() {
        return attemptId;
    }

    public long getScoreTimeStamp() {
        return scoreTimeStamp;
    }

    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((attemptId == null) ? 0 : attemptId.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((cardId == null) ? 0 : cardId.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + score;
        result = prime * result + (int) (scoreTimeStamp ^ (scoreTimeStamp >>> 32));
        result = prime * result + ((userId == null) ? 0 : userId.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        ScoreCard other = (ScoreCard) obj;
        if (attemptId == null) {
            if (other.attemptId != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!attemptId.equals(other.attemptId))
            return false;
        if (cardId == null) {
            if (other.cardId != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!cardId.equals(other.cardId))
            return false;
        if (score != other.score)
            return false;
        if (scoreTimeStamp != other.scoreTimeStamp)
            return false;
        if (userId == null) {
            if (other.userId != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!userId.equals(other.userId))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ScoreCard [cardId=" + cardId + ", userId=" + userId + ", attemptId=" + attemptId + ", scoreTimeStamp="
                + scoreTimeStamp + ", score=" + score + "]";
    }

}
```

**UserStatsController.java**

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/stats")
public class UserStatsController {

    private GameService gameService;

    @Autowired
    public UserStatsController(GameService gameService) {
        this.gameService = gameService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public GameStats getStatsForUser(@RequestParam("userId") Long userId) {
        return gameService.retrieveStatsForUser(userId);
    }

}
```

**applicaition.properties**

```
server.port=8081

spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/gamification;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
```

Comment: Can you provide you `Configuration` class. Check if you have enabled `JpaRepositories`. Add `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = ["base packages for jpa repositories"])`

Comment: Also can you provide db schema?

Comment: No, I didn't enable the JpaRepositories. and I didn't use any Configuration Class, I am using the application.properties file

Comment: @Andronicus, I am using the H2 database, and to check the schema of the H2 database, I required the spring boot application to run and till now I am unable to run the application.

Comment: @Prashant, I am getting the below error, after adding the @EnableJpaRepositories() annotation.                                                                        Consider defining a bean of type 'microservices.book.gamification.repository.ScoreCardRepository' in your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the `findByUserIdOrderByScoreTimestampDesc` to `findByUserIdOrderByScoreTimeStampDesc`.

Explanation: The properties of Entity Class must match with the Default Naming Strategy (unless configured specifically.)

I hope, this works.

Your Entity class is having property name as `scoreTimeStamp` (s in capital for timestamp word), but in Method Declaration, it is `ScoreTimestamp` (s in lowercase for timestamp word).

PS: By the information you provided in Question and following comments, this should only be the problem.

Comment: I tried the above procedure, still getting the same error.

Comment: Is it working if you remove/comment that specific method from repository interface.? Can you confirm?

Comment: I changed the method signature so that it becomes compatible with the Default Naming Strategy. I didn't remove or comment on the method, as it introduces errors in other parts of the code.

Comment: then just put a Query annotation over it and put simple select statement for ScoreCard to see if it is the only problem..?

You can put this under the query.. `SELECT * FROM microservices.book.gamification.domain.ScoreCard`

Comment: getting below error: **Description:**
Parameter 0 of constructor in microservices.book.gamification.service.LeaderBoardServiceImpl required a bean of type 'microservices.book.gamification.repository.ScoreCardRepository' that could not be found.


**Action:**

Consider defining a bean of type 'microservices.book.gamification.repository.ScoreCardRepository' in your configuration.

Comment: can you share the github or any link to repo ?

Comment: Can I share my repository file? As I didn't upload this project on github yet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198926/discussion-between-miiiii-and-farhanlq).